# sorting a list of objects_python_3

Tags: list, python-3.x, class, sorting

How can i sort "cardsListObj" with suit and then rank?
I've done something like "print (cardsListObj.sort (key = card.getRank))" and it didn't work, i have "None".
Actually i did this on another code that is quite the same as this (in my opinion as a newbie) and that worked. (that code is about 300 lines that's why i didn't post it, here)

```
class card :

    def __init__ (self, rank, suit) :

        self.rank = rank # cards numbers
        self.suit = suit # cards characters Diamonds, Clubs, Hearts, Spades

    def getRank (self):

        return self.rank

    def getSuit (self):

        return self.suit

def main():

    cards = open (input ("file? "))
    cardsListObj = []

    for i in cards:

        cardObj = card (i.split () [0], i.split () [1])
        cardsListObj.append (cardObj)
```

Input file is a txt file with a number and a name of cards in each line separated by space.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Were you doing something like `print(cardsListObj.sort(...`, perhaps?  `.sort()` returns None, its actual output is a modification to the list you called it on.  You'd need a separate `print(cardsListObj)` to see the sorted list.

Comment: Thank you, i get the point of having a "None", but using print (cardsListObj) gives me the location of the sorted objects by defined key. I'm also looking for a way to see the list by attribute of the objects, after sorting it. (is it possible?)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but perhaps you need to define `__str__()` and `__repr()__` methods on your class so that its instances print how you want, rather than "<card object at...>".

Comment: sorry if my question looks weird or unintelligible, I'm a beginner in programming. every object has a rank and suit, what I'm looking for is something like, [1,5,7,8,10] if I was going to print the sorted list by rank, and ["club", "club", "diamond","heart", "spade"] if getSuit was the sorting key.

Comment: Try `list(card.getRank() for card in cardsListObj)` - that's called a "list comprehension".

Answer (score 0):

if you want to sort your cards, you can create a function like this:

```
from operator import attrgetter

def sort_cards(cards): #cards is an list containing 'Cards' objects
    """Function sorting cards"""

    return sorted(cards, key=attrgetter('suit', 'rank'))

deck = [
    Cards(3, 'Diamonds'),
    Cards(7, 'Clubs'),
    Cards(5, 'Hearts'),
    Cards(8, 'Diamonds'),
    Cards(4, 'Spades'),
    Cards(10, 'Clubs')
]
print(sort_cards(deck))
```

Output (you should define the method `__repr__`)

```
['7 of Clubs', '10 of Clubs', '3 of Diamonds', '8 of Diamonds', '5 of Hearts', '4 of Spades']
```

**NB**:
In my example, `__repr__` is something like that:

```
class Card:

[...]

def __repr__(self):
    return '%d of %s' % (self.rank, self.suit)
```